# Data annotation + ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and have an ActionFilterAttribute which sets a boolean value X received by my action. I am also using data annotation to validate the received view model. I am just wondering if the OnActionExecuting is executed before the data annotation validation kicks in. If so is it possible to set the value of a view model property via the ActionFilterAttribute?

Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model Validation is executed in model binding **before any ActionFilters** except the Authorization filters. So I think that setting that value in the ActionFilterAttribute will not have effect on validation because it has already occured at that point of time.

The only thing I see right now is to make your custom model binder.

Comment: yeah I just figured this myself. Do you reckon I could make the ActionFilterAttribute an Authorization filter? This might be an option.

Comment: It would be preferable to do a custom model binder as the Authorization filter is not supossed to make the validation. It's better to keep the same semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Validation is triggered by model binder. This happens before OnActionExecuting. You could make a custom model binder which would set value and than trigger validation.